# Is chrome 84 webdriver compatible with selenium 3.141.0?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I was trying an automation project with selenium 3.141.0 and chrome 84 driver. But the code was getting stuck despite adding correct id and details. I would like to know whether its a compatibility issue or something else.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be - I tried selenium 3.141.0 and chrome 84 driver (I downloaded the Mac version from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and it works.

Are you sure your driver is compatible with your browser binary (that was an issue I've run into when using selenium previously)? And what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I was making a FB automation project.

`from selenium import webdriver`

`from time import sleep`

`driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\samar\OneDrive\Desktop\MAIN\projects\Jarvis\chromedriver.exe')`

`driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')`

`email=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="email"]')`

`email.send_keys('username')`

`password=driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="pass"]')`

`'''with open('pass.txt','r') as myfile:`
    `password1=myfile.read().replace('\n','')'''`

`password.send_keys('password')`

`login=driver.find_element_by_id('u_0_b')`

`login.click()`

`sleep(3)`

`postarea=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div')`

`postarea.click()`

`sleep(3)`

`activepostarea=driver.switch_to_active_element()`

`activepostarea.send_keys("Hello World")`

But as it reached the FB homepage after login. A message popped up for asking permission for notification i.e. allow or block. And then the following error came.

`raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mount_0_0"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div"} (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)`

Comment: It can't find that element based on that xpath. Inspect the element and copy the xpath , make sure it's not in an iframe and close the popup.

Comment: If the xpath is correct then will it works after closing the pop-up?